# How can I prevent Linux OS from waking up from sleep mode by pressing buttons?

Tags: keyboard, sleep

I often switch my Fedora Linux computer into sleep mode. However, I do not want it to wake up when pressing any button on the keyboard (except for the Power button). What can I do in order to achieve such behavior?

Comment: Please consult with this manual which provides all the necessary information: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Power_management/Wakeup_triggers The vast majority of laptops do not have such BIOS settings, so there's nothing you can configure. Certain desktop motherboards do not have such settings either.

Answer (score 5):

You can check your computer's firmware (I assume EFI, might be BIOS) settings. Somewhere there should be some settings in regard to power management. There probably is some "wake on keyboard" or "wake on USB" setting you want to disable.

Comment: Pretty much all laptops don't have these settings and quite a lot of desktop motherboards.

Comment: I believe this was part of the old APM specification, but modern ACPI BIOSes give most of this control to the OS after it's loaded.

Comment: I just realized that the newest system of mine was manufactured more than ten years ago. Now I feel old.

Answer (score 1):

Wakeup from standby can happen when pressing the power button or via USB input, as you observed. In Linux, wakeup from USB input can be disabled via the `/sys` interface. Here is a simple bash script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
for f in /sys/bus/usb/devices/*/power/wakeup; do
        echo disabled > $f;
done
```

Explanation: For each USB device, a folder is linked in the path `/sys/bus/usb/devices`. Each of these folder has a subfolder called `power` which contains a file `wakeup` that configures if this USB device should be allowed to wake the system up from standby. Running the script above writes a `disabled` into each `wakeup` file, therefore disabling each USB device from waking up the machine.

Note that this script must be executed as root and on every boot, because the change is not persistent. Furthermore it must be applied when a new device is connected to the machine. Personally, I have this line in my root’s crontab

```
*/5 *   *   *   *    bash /root/disable-usb-wakeup.sh
```

to run the script every 5 minutes, ensuring that wakeup via USB input does not happen.

Comment: This looks to me like something to add as a udev rule for a slight performance advantage over a cron job. I'll have to review the syntax file, however, before I can write an answer here.

Comment: @penguin359 You will also need `udevadm` running in `monitor` mode, to confirm that your rules really work as you expect.